# #include <afxinet.h> in a header file causes a lot of compilation error, however, include it in a cpp file is ok

Tags: c++, compilation, header, include

the first error when putting `#include <afxinet.h>` in a header file
IntelliSense: #error directive: WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not `#include <windows.h>`

(1) Any idea why this is it?

The other similar thing is if you put the headers in a wrong order, odd errors appear, whose msg do not make sense at all... this kind of behaviour of VC++ complier is driving me crazy.

(2)anyone has a solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with `winsock.h`, something like that:

`fatal error C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included`

I've added the `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` preprocessor directive to my project and it fixed it.

I can't tell why, or what is the reason behind that.

Comment: i think this kind of things are one of the reasons make people prefer other more robust languages like C#. It just make beginners feel so frustrated.